# Why does lsattr return Operation not supported While reading flags on .git/objects error message

Tags: linux

I try to check the attributes of some write-protected files in the.git directory using the command **lsattr**.

---

1. `$ lsattr .git/objects/4d/8595f02d97d82a3c4464d9fc1bc47b255dd9bf`

   lsattr: Operation not supported While reading flags on .git/objects/4d/8595f02d97d82a3c4464d9fc1bc47b255dd9bf
2. `$ stat .git/objects/4d/8595f02d97d82a3c4464d9fc1bc47b255dd9bf`

   File: .git/objects/4d/8595f02d97d82a3c4464d9fc1bc47b255dd9bf 
   Size: 115 Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
   Device: 0,36    Inode: 436         Links: 1
   Access: (0444/-r--r--r--)  Uid: ( 1000/    test)   Gid: ( 1000/    test)
3. `$ file .git/objects/4d/8595f02d97d82a3c4464d9fc1bc47b255dd9bf`
   .git/objects/4d/8595f02d97d82a3c4464d9fc1bc47b255dd9bf: zlib compressed data
4. `$ git -v`
   git version 2.39.1
5. `uname -r`
   5.15.91-1-MANJARO\

I'd like to figure out why lsattr can't get the attributes of some files and how to make such files.

EDIT. Those files are on the tmpfs filesystem.

Comment: Some files or all files? `lsattr -R .git` ?

Comment: @phd All files in .git directory

Comment: Most probably it's on a filesystem that doesn't support extended attributes.

Comment: It's on tmpfs filesystem on /tmp

Comment: `tmpfs` definitely doesn't support extended attributes!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The tmpfs filesystem supports extended attributes, but user extended attributes are not permitted. Noted from [lsattr man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/tmpfs.5.html)

Comment: This seems borderline, but I think https://unix.stackexchange.com/ would be a slightly better place for this kind of question.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance. I'm new in this area and don't know everything about all of the places and their functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because user extended attributes are not permitted on the tmpfs filesystem, this occurs. However, by enabling [TMPFS_XATTR](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/fs/Kconfig?h=v5.9.3#n189) in kernel configuration, extended attributes on tmfps can be enabled.